# Detect change in NSMutableOrderedSet with Swift Combine

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, combine, nsmutableset

I'm trying to observe change of an NSMutableOrderedSet in my ViewModel with combine.
I want to know when some element is added or removed of NSMutableOrderedSet

Some code of my ViewModel :

```
    class TrainingAddExerciceViewModel: ObservableObject {
        
        @Published var exercice: Exercice?
        @Published var serieHistories = NSMutableOrderedSet()
    
    ...
      init(...) {
        ...
        
//Where i'm trying to observe 
        $serieHistories
            .sink { (value) in
                print(value)
        }
        .store(in: &self.cancellables)
    }
    
    }
```

This is the function I use in my ViewModel to add element to NSMutableOrderedSet :

```
func add(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let newSerieHistory = ExerciceSerieHistory(context: managedObjectContext)
        self.serieHistories.add(newSerieHistory)
        self.updateView()
    }
```

I have some other publisher working well with an other type (custom class).

Did I miss something ?

Comment: it doesn't work with `NMutableOrderedSet` because it's a reference-type - a `class`. There's no "change" - it's the same reference - when you add another element

Comment: I missed this thing ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood logic of your code try the following (that `init` not needed)

1. variant 1 - add force update

   func updateView() {

   ```
    // ... other code

    self.objectWillChange.send()
   ```

   }
2. variant 2 - recreate storage

```
func add(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let newSerieHistory = ExerciceSerieHistory(context: managedObjectContext)
        let newStorage = NSMutableOrderedSet(orderedSet: self.serieHistories)

        newStorage.add(newSerieHistory)
        self.serieHistories = newStorage     // << fires publisher

        self.updateView()
    }
```

Comment: Variant 1 was already in updateView().
Variant 2 work well.
Solved ! thanks